# Href bull - doesn't appear

Tags: css, css-position

```
<div id="map" class="cf">
    <a href="#" class="bull washdc"></a>
</div> <!-- /#map -->


#map a.bull{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    color:red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#map a.washdc{
    top:10px;
    left:100px;
}
```

I am having trouble displaying this link. I have set the width and height, but the red background does not appear.

Comment: It might be relatively positioned to something else, or behind something if `#map` or `.cf` isn't set to `position: relative;`

Comment: **The background isn't set to red**...the text color is..and you don't have any text.

Answer (score 0):

Your .bull anchor doesn't have anything in it or a background so it's not going to show you anything, because there is nothing to see.. Try this.. See it working [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJbph)

```
#map a.bull{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  color:red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, the **'color'-attribute** assigns the color of the text.

Since you don't have any text in there, there won't be any text becoming red.
In your case you should add a **'background-color'** to make something show up.